# activity is gone and the created handler is still in use

Tags: android

An Activity created a handler in a method and passed it on to a singleton. Singleton holds this handler so that it can send the message back to activity. Activity handles the message in that local method by implementing the handleMessage(Message mesg) methond.

What happens if the activity gets destroyed and singleton tries to send the message via the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Once handler starts it does not stop.

Try AsyncTask it may be canceled or  interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

u can remove handler when activity is destryed.

Comment: I know it can be removed. But since if it is not removing then what happens and that is exactly the question.